# compare one object of my db4o with other new object

Tags: java, android, db4o

i'm using db4o with objects:

```
 public Tra(String x, int y, int z, int pos, Date de, Date de2)
```

I receive a new object (tram) and I want compare only three arguments (String x, int y, int z).

because the other arguments hasn't values yet.

I'm using:

```
Tra proto = new Tra(trat.getx(),trat.gety(),trat.getz(),0,null,null);
            ObjectSet result=db4oHelper.db().queryByExample(proto);
            if(result.equals(tram)){
                Log.d(TAG,"already exists");
            }
```

but doesn't work :(

Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have overridden the behavior in your custom model class, the Java language implementation of `.equals()` only returns true if both parameters are actually the same object (meaning the same memory address), not necessarily just equivalent. [According to the DB4O documentation](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/api/com/db4o/ObjectSet.html), `ObjectSet` is a collection, which could not possibly be the same object as your custom prototype `Tra`.  So you have two problems:

1. The value you are querying against isn't correct.  You probably want to do something more like `result.getNext().equals(tram)` to access the actual model object in the collection (keeping in mind there may be more than one).
2. You need to have a custom implementation of `equals()` in your model class to denote that they are equal if x, y and z are the same.

The second issue being handled by something like this:

```
public class Tra {

    /* Existing Code */

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (obj == this) return true;

        if (obj instanceof Tra) {
            Tra param = (Tra) obj;
            return this.x == param.x
                    && this.y == param.y
                    && this.z == param.z;
        }
    }
}
```

HTH